# Jquery load div with fb post one by one

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

I have a page with several facebook posts that I load with the code below (using fb sdk). However, the more I add reviews to the page the more the page takes to load, sometimes exceeding more than 10 seconds showing a blank page because the reviews are all shown at once. I'm wondering if there is a way with jquery to show the reviews one by one, i.e. start loading a div containing a post only after the previous div has been loaded. Is that something doable in jquery?

```
#1st post
<div class="containerReviews">
<center><div class="fb-post-container">
<div class="fb-post" 
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/name/posts/12345678910"
      data-width="500"></div>
</div></center>
</br>

#2nd post
<div class="containerReviews">
<center><div class="fb-post-container">
<div class="fb-post" 
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/name/posts/12345678910"
      data-width="500"></div>
</div></center>
</br>
#etc
```

Thanks,

Edit:
I've tried the following code, I can see the alert dialog and the first review but the second review doesn't show...

```
<script>
finished_rendering = function() {
    //alert("test")
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('divFB2'))
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //FB.XFBML.parse();
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('divFB1'));
    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', finished_rendering);
</script>
```

Comment: `FB.XFBML.parse` can be used to parse elements in specific parts of the DOM only, and if you subscribe to the `xfbml.render` event, you can probably get your script notified after one is done, so you can proceed to get the next one parsed. (Although that event probably doesn’t wait until the iframes have fully loaded.)

Comment: Thanks, please see edit to the original question, I managed to fire a callback after xfbml.render event but the second XFBML.parse doesn't show anything...